# DialogFlow - Returning a long response from the webhook via paged results

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a custom DialogFlow that on fulfilment, processes the user input and extracts a search keyword. DialogFlow then sends the search keyword to my Webhook.

My Webhook looks up the search keyword in a database that I have, and returns the result back.

Now, this mostly works great as long as the results are short. The user searches, and the results are returned back and is read by Google Assistant.

But when the results are long and exceed a certain character count, the search results get cut and are followed by ellipses. This is very shortly followed by a "Google Assistant Not Responding" error message. It might be worth noting that Google Assistant doesn't even manage to begin to read the text. It just crashes.

Now, what I want to happen is for the long results to be displayed. Something similar to when you ask Google Assistant to look up movies:

[image: Movie list result]

Or maybe even a paged result that a user can scroll through.

Comment: If you have an output that you see today that you want to replicate, my attack would be to try and determine what is being sent by Actions on Google that causes the desired output today.  Looking at your example, it feels like some kind of carousel of cards that have titles, a link and some text.

Comment: Are you asking about this for the Google Assistant specifically, or for other Dialogflow integrations as well?

Comment: @Prisoner I'm asking this about the DialogFlow integrations. How do I implement something similar to my DialogFlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Dialogflow integration (Facebook, Slack, Actions on Google, etc) has different features, capabilities, and limits. There is no one solution that will work for all of them.

If you are giving a long answer, however, keep in mind that some of the formats aren't well suited for long answers and this can create a poor UX. Spoken answers on the Assistant, for example, should be kept short.

If you are looking for a reply along the lines of what you illustrate, you can use something like multiple [cards](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/rich-messages#card) to represent the various replies. Some platforms, such as Facebook, will support this. If you're developing for the Assistant, Actions on Google supports a [Carousel/List](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#visual_selection_responses) visual selector.

Comment: Actually I was about to edit the question. I've made my webhook return fulfillmentMessages and Cards. When I try it on DialogFlow, it works, but it crashes on Actions on Google and when I test on my device. I'll check out the Carousel/List visual selector and figure out how to make my Python Webhook return that. Thank you!

Comment: If you do have problems doing so, ask another question and show the code that you're using.